# Loading layer from PostGIS database

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, layers

I'm trying to load a layer from a PostGIS database using PyQGIS.
The code is:

```
import os
from qgis.core import *

project = QgsProject.instance()
project.clear()

uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "db_name", "user", "pass")
uri.setDataSource("public", "table_name", "the_geom", "")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), "table_name", "postgres")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    project.addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

The problem is that I don't know what to write in "**the_geom**" (I tried to insert "point" or something similar).

Is there someone who can tell me?

Comment: We can't know what the `geometry` column in your table is unless you give us the table definition in the question body. While `geom` and `shape` are common, there really is nothing stopping the column from being named `avacado_field` or `fhhfghjitrewqutrchhfvhhgghgd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uri.setDataSource("public", "table_name", "the_geom", "query")`

- `public` refers to the name of your schema
- `table_name` refers to the table you want to load
- `the_geom` refers to the name of the geometry column (usually `the_geom` or `geom`)
- `query` refers to a filter, if you don't put anything in, the whole table will be loaded. For example, `id > 10`

Comment: Doesn't `"geom",` need to be followed by `"polygon"` or `"point"` in this case?

Comment: Replace `"geom"` with the name of your geometry column.